# Anonymize Public Health Records Database

Tags: algorithms, database

I am working on a project to anonymize PHI in our health records database when databases are copied to our testing environments. Currently, the database is copied and fields in the tables (first name, last name, address, DOB, etc.) are replaced pseudo-randomly (seed value generated by datetime) with values from a pre-generated list of values. For small databases this is fine, but when using very large databases with large tables values are repeated quite frequently and the scrubbing process takes a very long time. My thought was to use an algorithm that swaps values in the table, but is this a safe way to anonymize PHI? What types of algorithms would generate a sufficient variance in data while still maintaining a low processing time?

Comment: I don't think this question is answerable without seeing your current algorithms.  It's likely that there is a problem with the way they are written, but without looking at what you are doing now, it would be difficult to suggest alternatives.

Comment: When you say "scrub", do you actually mean "anonymize"?

Comment: Yes, I mean anonymize! My apologies. Scrub is a term used at our company for this, but anonymize is a much better term, thank you!

Comment: Even you current method is highly insecure. If you know some facts about a person (For example, I could know a priori your birthday and that you went to doctor *X* on date *Y*.) then I can easily match this information against your “anonymized” database and propagate the known links further to deanonymize other people.  I think the correct way to handle this is to do some statistics on your actual data, then build a model out of that and then pseudo-randomly generate a whole new database according to that model's distributions.

Comment: There are plenty of tools that exist specifically to do this sort of thing.  You certainly can roll you own.  But it is relatively unlikely that you would produce a solution that is more efficient and more effective than a commercial tool that has a bunch of developers focused just on that problem.

Comment: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/10/02/s_korean_anonymised_health_data_sharing_a_breach_in_waiting/

Comment: This is a well-researched area. A simple search on PubMed will produce hundreds of papers on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

> My thought was to use an algorithm that swaps values in the table, but is this a safe way to anonymize PHI?

No. You are still leaking information about your clients into the test environment.

It should be relatively trivial to generate an algorithm to randomly generate names (~100 first names + ~100 last names leads to a lot of combinations), addresses (number + tree + road/street/avenue/etc).

> For small databases this is fine, but when using very large databases with large tables values are repeated quite frequently and the scrubbing process takes a very long time.

Outside of performance/load testing, you probably don't *need* large databases for your test environments. It may be as simple as capping the number of rows (and their relations).

Comment: https://www.mockaroo.com/ and http://www.generatedata.com/ and I am sure others.

Answer (score -2):

I worked at a company where we did almost exactly what you are doing. I don't know exactly what our algorithm was. I do know that we scrambled the data so no one could ever unscramble it, but we did not change the data itself. Replacing names, addresses, and so forth with your own values sanitizes the data and eliminates any chance of catching some interesting errors. Real data is not perfect, and we I can't tell you how many bizarre little errors we found because of it.

If you are going to replace everything, then you should just generate the database you want, rather than trying to conform an existing one.